# Apportable - 'AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h' file not found

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, apportable

I have an iOS Objective C code for iPhone that I am trying to convert into android using [Apportable](http://apportable.com). The issue is that I am getting this error:

```
1 error generated.
scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.iapptechnologies.time/Users/Home/PhotoTastic/PhotoTastic/AppClasses/ViewController.m.o] Error 1
In file included from /Users/Home/PhotoTastic/PhotoTastic/OtherClasses/QBImagePickerController/QBAssetCollectionViewController.m:11:
/Users/Home/PhotoTastic/PhotoTastic/OtherClasses/QBImagePickerController/QBAssetCollectionViewController.h:12:9: fatal error: 
      'AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h' file not found
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
        ^
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is AssetsLibrary library added into the iOS project?

Comment: @LithuT.V No, it's just included via the #import directive. How do I add it to the iOS project? Leave your response as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that AssetsLibrary is not added automatically from parsing the xcode build.

A workaround is to add AssetsLibrary to the `"deps"` section of `"add_params"` in `configuration.json`

Note that AssetsLibrary is not available in the Starter version of the SDK. At least the Indie version is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do,In xcode 5 it looks different but the path is the same

[image: I think this will do]